# C++ iostream UTF-16 file I/O with CR LF translation

Tags: c++, newline, iostream, utf-16, codecvt

I want to read and write utf-16 files which use CR LF line separators (L"\r\n"). Using C++ (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010) iostreams. I want every L"\n" written to the stream to be translated to L"\r\n" transparently. Using the codecvt_utf16 locale facet requires to open the fstream in ios::binary mode, losing the usual text mode \n to \r\n translation.

```
std::wofstream wofs;
wofs.open("try_utf16.txt", std::ios::binary);
wofs.imbue(
    std::locale(
        wofs.getloc(),
        new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::generate_header>));
wofs << L"Hi!\n"; // i want a '\r' to be inserted before the '\n' in the output file
wofs.close();++
```

I want a solution without needing extra libraries like BOOST.

Comment: You are using Wide Chars. Wide characters are not guaranteed to be UTF-16. They too can be UTF-32. So, do not rely on them. If you are using C++, use char16_t instead.

Comment: @dbasic While `char16_t` is the correct solution, the C++11 support (and therefore the `char16_t` type) in VS2010 is very lacking.

Comment: Lacking by about a year, give or take a few months.  They can of course be blamed for not having programmed a time machine.

Comment: @HansPassant While it's true that it was made before the standard was published, the competition did have some functionality based on drafts (and the different between the last few drafts and the final spec was quite minimal) by that time.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: True, but just like the standard took some time to finalize after it was feature-complete, so did VS2010. I'm less forgiving about VS2012, though.

Comment: Thanks for this info. My program needs not to be portable, so wchar_t will do fine for now. In VS2010 there are many w-typedefs like wostream, wstring, but almost none for char16_t. I will change it when moving to a new VS version with full C++11 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a solution myself, I want to share it. Your comments are welcome!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class wcrlf_filebuf : public std::basic_filebuf<wchar_t>
{
    typedef std::basic_filebuf<wchar_t> BASE;
    wchar_t awch[128];
    bool bBomWritten;
public:
    wcrlf_filebuf() 
        : bBomWritten(false)
    { memset(awch, 0, sizeof awch); }

    wcrlf_filebuf(const wchar_t *wszFilespec, 
                  std::ios_base::open_mode _Mode = std::ios_base::out) 
        : bBomWritten(false)
    {
        memset(awch, 0, sizeof awch);
        BASE::open(wszFilespec, _Mode | std::ios_base::binary);
        pubsetbuf(awch, _countof(awch));
    }

    wcrlf_filebuf *open(const wchar_t *wszFilespec, 
                        std::ios_base::open_mode _Mode = std::ios_base::out)
    {   
        BASE::open(wszFilespec, _Mode | std::ios_base::binary);
        pubsetbuf(awch, _countof(awch));
        return this;
    }

    virtual int_type overflow(int_type ch = traits_type::eof())
    {
        if (!bBomWritten) {
            bBomWritten = true;
            int_type iRet = BASE::overflow(0xfeff);
            if (iRet != traits_type::not_eof(0xfeff)) return iRet;
        }
        if (ch == '\n') {
            int_type iRet = BASE::overflow('\r');
            if (iRet != traits_type::not_eof('\r')) return iRet;
        }
        return BASE::overflow(ch);
    }
};

class wcrlfofstream : public std::wostream
{
    typedef std::wostream BASE;
public:
    wcrlfofstream(const wchar_t *wszFilespec, 
                  std::ios_base::open_mode _Mode = std::ios_base::out) 
        : std::wostream(new wcrlf_filebuf(wszFilespec, _Mode))
    {}

    wcrlf_filebuf* rdbuf()
    {
        return dynamic_cast<wcrlf_filebuf*>(std::wostream::rdbuf());
    }

    void close()
    {
        rdbuf()->close();
    }
};
```